# How to take the string &XXXX& from a big string

Tags: regex, abap

Is there any way to take out from a big string a part of it which included in &&?
I know that I can find the 1st & and then the 2nd and take it out.
But is there any other way?

Thanks
Elias

Comment: Do you want a lazy or a greedy match?

Comment: A quick one and not find the 1st and 2nd and then take the string.

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question across so to elaborate: Given the string 'foo & bar & bad & boo', do you want to take out 'bar' (lazy match) or 'bar & bad' (greedy match)?

Comment: The string is: 'food &bar& &bad& boo'. Always the words will be between &&. So I want to take every &xxx& and do something with them.

Comment: So you're looking for a lazy match. As for "Always the words will be..." - I've seen too much user input to trust in statements like that :-) Next question - will you need to replace the part or just read and process it elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but I think you are searching this:

```
DATA: lv_text TYPE string.
lv_text = 'food &bar& &bad& boo'.

REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX   '&[^&]+&'  IN lv_text WITH ''.

WRITE lv_text.
```

Explanation of the REGEX `&[^&]+&`:

First & must be matched.

Then with `[^&]` anything but & must be matched, and the `+` means "one or more times".

At the end a & must be matched again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPLIT ... AT '&' INTO ... construcion to split the big string into three parts and then take the 2nd part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [string function](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstring_functions.htm):

```
DATA(result) = match( val = your_string regex = '&.+&' ).
```

Comment: If I copy-paste this line will it work? Or I must declare sth? Thanks.

Comment: You're gonna have to test it yourself :) but it should work and place `&bar& &bad&` from your example string mentioned above into `result`.

Comment: I test it but it doesn't work. My string is: 'My name is &name& and I work for &company& in &country&.' . How to get the name/company/country one by one in order to do some work for each one.  Your solution took from the 1st & until the last one. Thanks

Comment: You should provide more information in the original question, otherwise people are just guessing. And now I'm guessing you could do a simple `SPLIT ... INTO TABLE` and do your processing in a loop.